# Why didn't Kylo Ren detect Han Solo on Takodana?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Shortly after Han Solo, Chewbacca, and Finn arrive on Starkiller base to disable the shield, we see Kylo Ren, from an unspecified distance away, pause mid-sentence and mumble to himself, "Han Solo." I assume this means Ren has detected Solo through the force, in the same way Darth Vader detected Obi-Wan Kenobi on the Death Star in *A New Hope*.

Why did this not happen when Ren and Solo were on Takodana at the same time?

Comment: Ren expected Han to be on Takodana. There was no reason to be surprised or make a comment about it. Han showing up at Starkiller was unexpected.

Comment: @phantom42 sounds like that's worthy of an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### He probably did

On Starkiller base, Kylo senses the presence of Han, as you said:

> KYLO REN:
>              Put every hangar on lock-down. She's
>              going to try to steal a ship to--
>             Suddenly, Kylo senses something. Something familiar.
>
> KYLO REN (CONT'D):
>              Han Solo...

I'm not sure we can conclude that he *didn't* sense Han on Takodana, though. In particular, he might already have know Han was there if he saw the *Millenium Falcon*.

Even if he had known Han was on Takodana, any attempt he might have made at that point

> to kill him

would have been hindered by the arrival of the Resistance forces. **His priority was to take Rey and find out what she knew about the map.**

By contrast, on Starkiller base he was surrounded by allies, and thus could give priority to

> killing his father.

Just because we don't see him noticing Han's presence onscreen, doesn't mean he didn't. It was simply more plot-relevant to show it later.

In addition, when Kylo was on Takodana he might have been distracted by his desire to capture Rey, which could have distracted him from Han's presence.

Comment: In addition in both the novelisation and a deleted scene (on the official DVD) there is a scene with Kylo **on** the Falcon, standing in the cockpit and sensing his father's presense.

Comment: feel free to add it to your answer for that additional Correct Answer chewy flavour! ;)

Comment: Does that novelized/deleted scene with Ren and the _Falcon_ take place on Takodana or Starkiller? The _Falcon_ didn't crash on Takodana.

Comment: Argh, yes, mea culpa! Takodana is/was Maz' castle, d'oh.